# UITextField inside UITableViewCell gets erased on scroll

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a small form (5 fields) in a grouped UITableView.  Each UITextField is inside of a UITableView cell.  When clicking in a textField, it brings up the keyboard, which then allows you to scroll some of the cells out of view, when you pull them back down, their content is erased.

Am I correct in assuming that they have been redrawn, so their content is gone?  If so, what is the best way to prevent this?  Since I only have 5 fields, do I have to redraw my cells when the are scrolled back into view?

I am reusing cells:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a separate array of you text fields and implement you cell creation callback like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath 
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }
    [[cell.contentView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    [cell.contentView addSubview: [textFieldsArray objectsAtIndex: indexPath.row]];

    return cell;

}
```